# Arduino LED project, initially lighting the led

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, led

I'm starting my first arduino project, and basically am having some trouble with the initial set up. I'm trying to light one led pixel. Here is the link to the led pixels I'm using [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01D1FFVOA/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01D1FFVOA).

I soldered two wires to the 5v lead and the gnd lead and connected them to the 5v and the ground pin on the UNO R3 microcontroller. Is the led supposed to light up right away or do I need to program the microcontroller to do that?

Appreciate any guidance with this. Thanks

Comment: You have to send this LED info via the Data In pin. [This](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/overview) tutorial by Adafruit should address that.

Answer (score 1):

The smart led has a small controller ic built in,  and won't light until data is sent to it. You must program your Arduino with the appropriate code to drive the led.